# Correlation of belief distributions from distinct signals

Tags: probability-theory, game-theory, bayesian

Anne and Bob are two Bayesians who initially share a non-degenerate prior about a binary state of the world.  Anne observes some signal (i.e., an experiment in Blackwell's terminology) about the state of the world.  (Formally, a signal/experiment is a joint distribution on the state of the world and the data that Anne observes.)  Observing this signal induces some distribution of Anne's posterior beliefs. Denote that distribution on $[0,1]$ by $A$.

Bob also observes a signal (not necessarily the same as Anne's, not necessarily conditionally independent from Anne's, etc.) about the true state of the world.  Let $B$ denote the distribution of Bob's posterior beliefs.

What can we say about the relationship between random variables $A$ and $B$? For example, are $A$ and $B$ necessarily (strictly) positively correlated? Are there any other restrictions on their joint distribution?

I specified a binary state of the world so supports of $A$ and $B$ are in $[0,1]$ and it is easy to talk about their correlation, but any results that apply to an arbitrary state space would also be of great interest.

Comment: Did you mean $\{0,1\}$ rather than $[0,1]$?  The former, $\{0,1\}$ is a set with only two elements, so it is binary.  The latter, $[0,1]$ is a set containing not only $0$ and $1$ but also all numbers between them. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I meant $[0,1]$.  The state space is $\{0,1\}$ but beliefs about the state are in $[0,1]$.  (You can associate a belief with the probability that the state is $1$).  Hence, distributions $A$ and $B$ have support in $[0,1]$

Comment: Then you not being clear.  What is the quantity in $[0,1]$ to which you are assigning a distribution expressing uncertainty about its value? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: A distribution on $[0,1]$ that assigns probability $0.75$ to the interval $[0.4,0.5]\subseteq[0,1]$ means the probability is $0.75$ that some particular quantity is between $0.4$ and $0.5$. A _binary_ state of the world means something like this: either international bankers induced Lee Harvey Oswald to kill John F. Kennedy or they did not.  You can assign probability $0.2$ to the proposition that international bankers induced Lee Harvey Oswald to kill John F. Kennedy, and then the probability that they did not is $0.8$. So where is the distribution on $[0,1]$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: The state space is binary, $\{0,1\}$.  A signal realization, or an outcome of the experiment, induces a belief, i.e., a distribution on $\{0,1\}$.  The set of distributions on $\{0,1\}$ is isomorphic to the unit interval $[0,1]$.  So each outcome of an experiment induces an element of $[0,1]$.  The overall experiment thus induces a distribution over beliefs, i.e., a distribution over distributions on $\{0,1\}$, i.e., a distribution over $[0,1]$.